# Even trigonometric functions are dense

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $C([0,K])$ be the space of continuous functions on $[0,K]$ for $K>0$. Consider all linear combinations of $(\cos(a x))_{a\in \mathbb{N}}$ defined on $[0,K]$. Is it true that these are dense in $C[0,K]$ if $K=\pi$ but not if $K>\pi$? I don't see how I can show or disprove that property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets first replace $C([0,x])$ with $C([0,K])$, so we do not have two $x$'s running around.

Suppose $K>\pi$.  Then there is some $\epsilon>0$ small enough so that $\pi-\epsilon$ and $\pi+\epsilon$ are both in $[0,K]$.  Now, for any $a\in\mathbb{N}$, $\cos(a(\pi-\epsilon))=\cos(a(\pi+\epsilon))$.

Thus if $f$ is a function in $C[(0,K)]$ with $f(\pi-\epsilon)\neq f(\pi+\epsilon)$, it cannot be a limit (with respect to the sup norm) of linear combinations of $(\cos(ax))_{a\in\mathbb{N}}$.